# Changing the font of php code using css styling

Tags: php, html, css, forms, switch-statement

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Greeting Service!</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<style type="text/css">
#name {
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
}
#greet {
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['language'])) {
$language = $_POST['language'];
switch ($_POST['language']) {
case "option1":
$result = "Hello, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
break;
case "option2":
$result = "你好, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
break;
case "option3":
$result = "Bonjour, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
break;
}
echo $result;
} else {
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<h1 id="name">What's Your Name?</h1>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name Here" />
<h4 id="greet">Greet me in:
<select name="language">
<option value="option1">English</option>
<option value="option2">Chinese</option>
<option value="option3">French</option>
</select>
</h4>
<input type="submit" value="Greet Me!" />
</form>
</center>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure how i am able to change the font of the 'name' outputted from the text-box. Is it possible to use css styling in php code? I would like to change the font-weight and font-family of the text outputted from the text box. Thanks

Comment: This is what is called "CSS 101". Ask yourself this; "can a web developer also be a web designer"? ;-) *and vice-versa.*

Comment: Put it in an element then style as you have the others.

Comment: In your elements give them attributes then style it

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, you do it as you would always do for any CSS style applied immediately:

```
$result = "<p style="font-weight:val;font-family:val;">Hello, {$_POST['name']}!</p>";
```

You can change these values however you want and the styling should be displayed when you `echo` it out.

Alternatively as suggested below, you can just wrap `$result` with the CSS, or if you're looking to set different values, you can apply them in your switch case like this:

```
switch ($_POST['language']) {
case "option1":
$result = "Hello, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
$style = 'font-weight:val;font-family:val';
break;
case "option2":
$result = "你好, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
$style = 'font-weight:val;font-family:val';
break;
case "option3":
$result = "Bonjour, {$_POST['name']}!";
$style = 'font-weight:val;font-family:val';
break;
}
echo '<p style="' . $style . '">' . $result . '</p>';
```

Comment: It'd be better to just wrap the `$result` in the element...here `echo $result;`.

Comment: He/she may want different styles applied to different cases in the `switch` statement, but you're probably right.

Comment: I guess, he/she could also dynamically set the style values or styling code in the switch cases as well, made an edit

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Greeting Service!</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <style type="text/css">
        #name {
            font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
            font-weight: 700;
            background-color: red;
        }
        #greet {
            font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['language'])) {
        $language = $_POST['language'];
        switch ($_POST['language']) {
        case "option1":
        $result = "<p id=\"name\">Hello, {$_POST['name']}!</p>"; 
        break;
        case "option2":
        $result = "<p id=\"name\">你好, {$_POST['name']}!</p>"; 
        break;
        case "option3":
        $result = "<p id=\"name\">Bonjour, {$_POST['name']}!</p>"; 
        break;
        }
        echo $result;
        } else {
        ?>
            <form method="post" action="">
            <h1 id="name">What's Your Name?</h1>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name Here" />
            <h4 id="greet">Greet me in:
                <select name="language">
                    <option value="option1">English</option>
                    <option value="option2">Chinese</option>
                    <option value="option3">French</option>
                </select>
            </h4>
            <input type="submit" value="Greet Me!" />
            </form>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```